# Increase/Decrease ActiveCell's value on +/- keypress

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm making myself a game raid tracker in excel.

The table has dynamic sorting through VB code which is constantly active, unless I stop the code for a while. Now what I need is a piece of code which will make it so that when I select a cell and press either + or - on the keyboard's numpad, the value in the cell increases or decreases by 1, instead of the +/- being written inside the cell.

The sort code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error Resume Next
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A10:F192")) Is Nothing Then
Range("A10:F192").Sort _
Key1:=Range("C11"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
Key2:=Range("F11"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End If
End Sub
```

This is from memory, so it might be a bit off, but you should get the idea. So how do I implement the increase/decrease function to this?

Comment: The `Change` worksheet event would be fired *after* the cell exited edit mode, and then at that point you not only have the "+" or "-" in the cell, you've also lost the original cell value. Not sure you can implement this without some serious Win32 message interception. You can *easily* capture (and "eat") keypresses on a `UserForm`, not on a worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I fixed the numeric keypad catch.

I got it working with `SendKeys`. Add this to the `ThisWorkbook` object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    TogglePlusCatch
    ToggleMinusCatch
    Application.OnKey "{107}", "CatchPlus"
    Application.OnKey "{109}", "CatchMinus"
End Sub
```

And add this to a module:
    Option Explicit

```
Public blnCatchPlus As Boolean
Public blnCatchMinus As Boolean

Public Sub TogglePlusCatch()
    With Application
        If blnCatchPlus Then
            .OnKey "{+}"
            blnCatchPlus = False
        Else
            .OnKey "{+}", "CatchPlus"
            blnCatchPlus = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub CatchPlus()
    If blnCatchPlus Then
        Dim rngIntersection As Range

        Set rngIntersection = Intersect(Selection, Range("A10:F192"))

        If rngIntersection Is Nothing Then
            'the target range was not selected, so let the keystroke go through
            TogglePlusCatch
                SendKeys "{+}"
                DoEvents
            TogglePlusCatch
        Else
            IncrementOne rngIntersection, 1
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub ToggleMinusCatch()
    With Application
        If blnCatchMinus Then
            .OnKey "{-}"
            blnCatchMinus = False
        Else
            .OnKey "{-}", "CatchMinus"
            blnCatchMinus = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub CatchMinus()
    If blnCatchMinus Then
        Dim rngIntersection As Range

        Set rngIntersection = Intersect(Selection, Range("A10:F192"))

        If rngIntersection Is Nothing Then
            'the target range was not selected, so let the keystroke go through
            ToggleMinusCatch
                SendKeys "{-}"
                DoEvents
            ToggleMinusCatch
        Else
            IncrementOne rngIntersection, -1
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub IncrementOne(rngIntersection As Range, iIncrement As Integer)
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In rngIntersection
        rng = rng + iIncrement
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

place this in your worksheet code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rng As Range
Dim val As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Address = rng.Address Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case "+"
                    Target.Value = val + 1
                Case "-"
                    Target.Value = val - 1
            End Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 And IsNumeric(Target.Value2) Then
        Set rng = Target
        val = Target.Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @MarkoPomahač, did you try this?